# How to initialize a sub-formgroup in a child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

What I am trying to do is have formgroup in a parent component and have multiple child components each with their own sub-formgroup which will be initialized separately in their respective components.

I'm trying to use setValue(); but that doesn't seem to be working. It says

```
An argument for 'value' was not provided.
```

The end goal to see if it works is to change a value in a child component and subscribe to value changes in the parent component and see the new value reflected there.

I am omitting imports and constructors for brevity.

parent.component.ts

```
  overAllForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    panel1: [null],
  });

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.overAllForm.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
     console.log("Value Changed");
     console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

parent.component.html

```
<child-component [parentForm]="overAllForm"> </child-component>
```

child.component.ts

```
this.parentForm.get("panel1").setValue(
 this.fb.group({
   field1: ['']
   }));
 }
```

child.component.html

```
<input formControlName="field1"> </input>
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
childForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  childForm = this.fb.group({
    field1: ['']
    }));
  }
  this.parentForm.addControl('panel1', this.childForm);
}
```

This will trigger the value change event 1 time when the control is added but not when I start typing in the input.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that but I don't understand why would you need it, it seems to be  adding to the complexity of the code, why not just let the child component emit the value when it's needed in the parent component ? Anyway the issue with your code is you are adding a form group to the parent form group (this is possible and correct, but my guess is the binding to your view is messed up somehow), anyway I will demo an easier solution and more appropriate to your use case, since it is just one control you want to add to the parent control, what you need to do is add a form control to the parent form group, and bind that form control to the input in your view.

Child component

```
childControl: FormControl;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.childControl = new FormControl('');
  this.parentForm.addControl('field1', this.childControl);
}
```

html

```
<input [formControl]="childControl"> </input>
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought, I did in-fact try that. (Its actually there at the bottom of my post).  The problem with that approach was that changing a field in the child component did not trigger a value change in the parent.  (That might even by by design) But anyway, if you know a way to overcome that hurdle I would appreciate it.

Comment: This should trigger value changes just fine, I already tried it, if you create a stackblitz I can look into it

Comment: The other thing is that, There is no form-group in the child component. That's a requirement

Comment: the input "parentForm" is already a form group, you can use it. Also when you use [formControl] binding, you don't need a form group.

Comment: My data model is a 1:1 mapping of my form. If there is a sub-form,  it's because there is a sub object in the data model.